# First response time calculation

Tags: powerbi, dax

everyone! I am trying to calculate the first response time as a calculated column, but I received a blank.

[image]

```
First Responce Time = 
VAR
 FisrtMTime = CALCULATE(MIN('Clients support data'[Message Time]), FILTER( ALLEXCEPT('Clients support data', 'Clients support data'[Ticket]), 'Clients support data'[Author Name] <> "Company Name" ))
VAR
 ResponceTime = CALCULATE(MIN('Clients support data'[Message Time]), FILTER( ALLEXCEPT('Clients support data', 'Clients support data'[Ticket]), 'Clients support data'[Author Name] = "Company Name" ))
RETURN
  DATEDIFF(ResponceTime, FisrtMTime, MINUTE)
```

I have added an example of my fact table and calculation that I have a problem to fix. I will appreciate any advice. Thanks.

[image]